# Resetting database once per test class in Laravel 5.4

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to work with Laravel 5.4 + PHPUnit for testing my classes. I created following class to test user controller:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
{
protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/pmv2';

use DatabaseMigrations;

public function testCreatesUser()
{
    echo "\nTest: POST /users => Create new user";

    $data = [
        'first_name'   => 'first_new_user',
        'last_name'    => 'last_new_user',
        'email'        => 'email_new@pm.com',
        'password'     => 'new_password',
        'phone_number' => '3333333333',
        'status'       => 'active',
        'created_at'   => '2000-1-1 10:10:00',
        'updated_at'   => '2000-1-1 10:10:00',
    ];

    $response = $this->post('/users', $data);
    $response->assertStatus(200);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', ['email' => $data['email']]);
}

public function testReadAllUsers()
{
    $this->seed('UsersTableSeeder');

    echo "\nTest: GET /users => Read all users";

    $this->seed('UsersTableSeeder');

    $response = $this->get('/users');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJson([
        'found' => true,
        'users' => [],
    ]);
}

public function testReadSingleUser()
{
    $this->seed('UsersTableSeeder');

    echo "\nTest: POST /users => Read single user";

    $response = $this->get('/users/1');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJson([
        'found' => true,
        'user'  => [],
    ]);

}

public function testUpdateUser()
{
    $this->seed('UsersTableSeeder');

    echo "\nTest: POST /users => Create new user";

    $data = [
        'first_name'   => 'first_updated_user',
        'last_name'    => 'last_updated_user',
        'email'        => 'email_updated@pm.com',
        'password'     => 'updated_password',
        'phone_number' => '44444444444',
        'updated_at'   => '2000-1-1 10:10:00',
    ];

    $response = $this->put('/users/1', $data);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', ['email' => $data['email']]);
}
}
```

The problem here is that database is refreshed for every single test. I need to refresh the migration only once before the very first test runs and after the last test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when a user is created? For example that exists one more user in database. For example you can count users before and after the POST calls.

You dont really need to test POST, but what happens when POST calls is committed.

And you dont test that a `/user/{id}` exists. This make test dependent to an id: tests MUST be independent. You can put in the same test a POST (to create the user), get the last id from the response or from the database and then GET that user. This is a way to check that exactly same user is in the database. And is a way to remove the id. If you depend on ids, the test run only once. Your tests must be repeatable.

Reset database each time costs too much. I suggest you to do the following steps:

1) recreate database with fixtures (just what you need for tests)
 2) run all tests

Remember also that tests must be fast. A test suite with a duration over 15/20 minutes is slow! You need to be fast.

Reading test `testReadSingleUser`, I suggest you to create the user "by hand", retrieve the id, finally to GET the user with that id. This makes the test repeatable infinite times.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a good idea: if you need this it means that your tests aren't independent and even the order of execution can afflict final result.

That's not good: you should follow FIRST principles

- F ast
- I ndependent / I solated
- R repeatable
- S elf validating
- T imely

Read more [here](https://github.com/ghsukumar/SFDC_Best_Practices/wiki/F.I.R.S.T-Principles-of-Unit-Testing)